# AttributeError in async kivy program

Tags: python, asynchronous, kivy, python-asyncio, attributeerror

could you please help me fix this program so that it won't show me an Attribute error.
I am a newbie to Async programming and I have barely any idea of what is going on.

Here is the code:

```
"""Example shows the recommended way of how to run Kivy with the Python built
in asyncio event loop as just another async coroutine.
"""
import asyncio

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

Builder.load_string('''BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        ToggleButton:
            id: btn1
            group: 'a'
            text: 'Sleeping'
            allow_no_selection: False
            on_state: if self.state == 'down': label.status = self.text
        ToggleButton:
            id: btn2
            group: 'a'
            text: 'Swimming'
            allow_no_selection: False
            on_state: if self.state == 'down': label.status = self.text
        ToggleButton:
            id: btn3
            group: 'a'
            text: 'Reading'
            allow_no_selection: False
            state: 'down'
            on_state: if self.state == 'down': label.status = self.text
    Label:
        id: label
        status: 'Reading'
        text: 'Beach status is "{}"'.format(self.status)''')

class MainLayout(Widget):

    other_task = None

    def app_func(self):
        """This will run both methods asynchronously and then block until they
        are finished
        """
        self.other_task = asyncio.ensure_future(self.waste_time_freely())

        async def run_wrapper():
            # we don't actually need to set asyncio as the lib because it is
            # the default, but it doesn't hurt to be explicit
            await self.async_run(async_lib='asyncio')
            print('App done')
            self.other_task.cancel()

        return asyncio.gather(run_wrapper(), self.other_task)

    async def waste_time_freely(self):
        """
        This method is also run by the asyncio loop and periodically prints
        something.
        """
        try:
            i = 0
            while True:
                if self.root is not None:
                    status = self.root.ids.label.status
                    print('{} on the beach'.format(status))

                    # get some sleep
                    if self.root.ids.btn1.state != 'down' and i >= 2:
                        i = 0
                        print('Yawn, getting tired. Going to sleep')
                        self.root.ids.btn1.trigger_action()

                i += 1
                await asyncio.sleep(2)
        except asyncio.CancelledError as e:
            print('Wasting time was canceled', e)
        finally:
            # when canceled, print that it finished
            print('Done wasting time')

class AsyncApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MainLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(MainLayout().app_func())
    loop.close()
```

[Here is the error shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnVqG.jpg)

Can you please fix the Attribute error for me and also how do I get rid of all the deprecation warnings?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

just in case you want a means to an end, and not specifically a correction to asyncio, I took the liberty of writing something the way I know: Threading.

as I ran the code it did not display the buttons nicely so I changed the top level to a BoxLayout and in the build string named the top level according to the top level Class Name 'MainLayout'

Kivy also provides a way to schedule tasks with kivy.clock and I occasionally use this in my kivy applications but more commonly use threads.

```
"""Example shows the recommended way of how to run Kivy with the Python built
in Threading
"""
import time
import threading
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


Builder.load_string('''<MainLayout>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            ToggleButton:
                id: btn1
                group: 'a'
                text: 'Sleeping'
                allow_no_selection: False
                on_state: if self.state == 'down': label.status = self.text
            ToggleButton:
                id: btn2
                group: 'a'
                text: 'Swimming'
                allow_no_selection: False
                on_press: root.kv_swim(self, my_argument = 'anything')
                on_state: if self.state == 'down': label.status = self.text
            ToggleButton:
                id: btn3
                group: 'a'
                text: 'Reading'
                allow_no_selection: False
                state: 'down'
                on_press: root.kv_read(self, my_argument = 'anything')
                on_state: if self.state == 'down': label.status = self.text
    Label:
        id: label
        status: 'Reading'
        text: 'Beach status is "{}"'.format(self.status)''')


class MainLayout(BoxLayout):

    other_task = None
    started_reading = False
    started_swimming = False

    def waste_time(self, task: str):
        while True:
            print(f"the task {task} is {time.time():.1f}")
            time.sleep(1.2)

    def kv_read(self, my_button, my_argument: str = "default_value"):
        print(f"you can send information from the button {my_argument}")
        if not self.started_reading:
            threading.Thread(target=self.waste_time, args=("read", ), daemon=True).start()
            self.started_reading = True
        else:
            print("don't start again")

    def kv_swim(self, my_button, my_argument: str = "default_value"):
        print(f"you can send information from the button {my_argument}")
        if not self.started_swimming:
            threading.Thread(target=self.waste_time, args=("swim", ), daemon=True).start()
            self.started_swimming = True
        else:
            print("don't start again")


class ThreadedApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MainLayout()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mine = ThreadedApp()
    mine.run()
```